# Translation in arabic store for You added {Product name } to your shopping cart

Tags: magento2, translate, arabic

I want to translate "You added {Product name } to you shopping cart in arabic.
I tried this,

"You added %1 to your <a href=""""%2"""">shopping cart.","لقد أضفت    %1 إلى <a href=""""2%""""> عربة التسوق .",,,,,,

But the output is https://prnt.sc/vxfex4
Please help

Comment: there is no closing 'a' tag ? 
what is wrong with this output? the sentence is translated.

Comment: @Rk Rathod Closing a tag is present "You added %1 to your <a href=""""%2"""">shopping cart</a>.","""لقد أضفت    %1 إلى <a href=""""2%""""> عربة التسوق </a>."""

Comment: Sentence is translated but the link in href shows %2  like <a href = "%2" >. How can i translate the link

Comment: you have space between 1 and %. and in arabic sentence you have wrong order in variable (2% and 1% but in english sentence you have %1 and %2)

Comment: Check updated question. Product name is translated but not the link inside href

Comment: "You added %1 to your <a href=""%2"">shopping cart</a>.","لقد أضفت %1 إلى <a href=""%2""> عربة التسوق</a>.", module Magento_Theme

Comment: above answer works for me. Please check